# CSS3 transform and transition doesn't work properly on firefox

Tags: css

I'm trying to make an affect on a box to drop 5px down when hovering.

It does work smoothly on Chrome but on firefox it's doesn't do the transition.

Please have a look at the next [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HhFAz) using firefox and using chrome

```
<div class="test"></div>

.test {
    background-color:blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    @include transition(transform .3s 0 ease);
    @include transform(translateY(0));
    &:hover {
      @include transform(translateY(5px));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your pen has no transition effect.

Comment: Its still same, can you paste your code here?

Comment: post your HTML and CSS here.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai posted my css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Padding

Here's my preferred method using only `padding`:
**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/EDHmH/)**

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.test {
    background-color:blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.test:hover {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.transition {
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

### Using Transform

Or if you still want to use `transform`:
**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/SL6uU/)**

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.test {
    background-color:blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.test:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(10p));
    -o-transform: translateY(10px);
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
.transition {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

As Kiran said already, each browser has varying support for directly using `transform` and `transition`. You can check who can use `transforms` [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) and `transitions` [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions).

Also take note that the `transition` wasn't applied to the `:hover`. It needs to be called at the base level (in this case at the `div` level).

Answer (score 0):

Hi i guess will might help you out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dHBni

check below css to find transitions property for different browsers

```
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: green;


}
```

for more information about transition http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/